# Handling an Error with custom parameter in an if-statement in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, swift3

I created a custom enum conforming to `Error` in Swift as such:

```
enum CustomError: Error{
    case errorWith(code: Int)
    case irrelevantError
}
```

`CustomError` can optionally be returned from an asynchronous function through a closure like so:

```
func possiblyReturnError(completion: (Error?) -> ()){
    completion(CustomError.errorWith(code: 100))
}
```

I would now like to check the type of `CustomError` that is returned in the closure. Along with that, if it is a `CustomError.errorWith(let code)`, would like to extract the code of that `CustomError.errorWith(let code)`. All of this I would like to be done using the condition of an if-statement. Along the lines of this:

```
{ (errorOrNil) in
    if let error = errorOrNil, error is CustomError, // check if it is an 
    //.errorWith(let code) and extract the code, if so
    {
        print(error)
    }
    else {
        print("The error is not a custom error with a code")
    }
}
```

Is this at all possible using Swift 3.0? I tried various combinations that I could think of, however, all attempts have been fruitless and ended in compilation time errors.

Comment: where you want to compare the error code ? Did you mean, By checking error code, you want to return some custom error message ?

Comment: That's more or less it. I want to handle the error differently for the two cases `CustomError.errorWith(let code)` and any other error. @Wolverine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
{ (errorOrNil) in
    if let error = errorOrNil as? CustomError, case let .errorWith(code) = error {
       print(code, error)
    } else {
       print("The error is not a custom error with a code")
    }
}
```

Or use `switch` instead of `if`.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `switch` expression

```
 if let error = error as? CustomError {
    switch error {
      case .errorWith(let code):
        print("error has code:" code)
      case .irrelevantError:
        print("irrelevantError")
    }

 } else if error != nil {
    print("The error is not a custom error with a code")
 }
```

Comment: Of course, a `switch` expression would work. However, since I would like to categorically just act on one specific type of error and the other types get a different "treatment", I'd say, I prefer @user28434 solution.